# How do I clear the WPF / XAML type cache in a plugin project

Tags: wpf, xaml, assemblies, xamlparseexception

I'm writing a plugin for an application (Autodesk Revit Architecture 2011, if you need to know).

During debugging, I'd like to recompile my plugin and reload that in the host. My specific host even provides an Add-In Manager that simplifies this process, using `Assembly.Load`. For Windows.Forms plugins, this works like a charm.

When I use WPF, this breaks down. At first, I was getting an error along these lines (I added some formatting to make it easier for you to read:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException:  
[A]MyApp.Controls.MyControl cannot be cast to [B]MyApp.Controls.MyControl. 
Type A originates from 'MyApp, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'LoadNeither' at location '%PATHA%'. 
Type B originates from 'MyApp, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'LoadNeither' at location '%PATHB'.  
Error at object 'MyApp.Controls.MyControl' in markup file 'MyApp;component/controls/mydialog.xaml'.
```

I have also taken the liberty of renaming controls, namespaces and paths to protect the innocent and me, the culprit.

I assume this is because the XAML parser keeps a cache of types it has already loaded.

My first step was to change the assembly versions, by setting `AssemblyInfo.cs/[assembly: AssemblyVersion("2.0.*")`. This just moves the error a step further:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException:  
Unable to cast object of type 'MyApp.Controls.MyControl' to type 'MyApp.Controls.MyControl'.  
Error at object 'MyApp.Controls.MyControl' in markup file 'MyApp;component/controls/mydialog.xaml'. 
---> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'MyApp.Controls.MyControl' to type 'MyApp.Controls.MyControl'.
```

Comment: Do the paths look like 'C:\Documents and Settings\Kilroy\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\ProjectAssemblies\yzwin42a31\MyDll.dll'?

Comment: how do they look like? Maybe that could help?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds to me like you'd be best off performing compilation in a separate `AppDomain`. You can then throw that `AppDomain` away once the compilation is done.

The exact interface between your main `AppDomain` and compilation `AppDomain`s is not really something I can comment on since you've not provided details in your question.

Comment: i think the host just uses Assembly.Load to load my plugin dll and then calls into an interface. this all happens in the same AppDomain and starting a new one is tricky: host api does not marshal :(

Comment: your comment suggests compilation of xaml at runtime?! i thought this was done at compile time...

Answer (score 2):

Don't know how to clean the cache, but as workaround I'd try to load XAML directly with XamlReader.Load and see if it works. 
Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms590388.aspx#Y309

Comment: I'll give it a try. me stupid started a bounty and then went on vacation. i only have a smartphone on me and can't verify. but +1 for a good idea to try :)